# '__reduce_cython__' error in Python while importing Pandas package in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

This is the Object Error which I received while importing Pandas. I have Anaconda and I am a Jupyter Notebook user. I am unable to troubleshoot this error.

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 import pandas

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     28 
     29 try:
---> 30     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
     31 except ImportError as e:  # pragma: no cover
     32     # hack but overkill to use re

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py in <module>
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 
----> 3 from .tslibs import (
      4     NaT,
      5     NaTType,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py in <module>
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 
----> 3 from .conversion import localize_pydatetime, normalize_date
      4 from .nattype import NaT, NaTType, iNaT, is_null_datetimelike
      5 from .np_datetime import OutOfBoundsDatetime

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion()

AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._TSObject' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Comment: what `pandas`, `cython` and `python` versions are you using? [Github](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1953#issuecomment-398128940)

Comment: @It_is_Chris pandas -> 0.25.1, Cython-> 0.29.13, Python -> 3.7.4

Comment: is your cython version greater than 0.28?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Yes it is

Comment: When you installed pandas was it compiled with an older version of cython?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219749/discussion-between-ricky-rick-and-it-is-chris).